# Ubuntu 18.04 shutdown 0 takes several minutes

Tags: 18.04

> When I do

```
shutdown 0
```

> it takes around 10 or 15 minutes to shutdown

Comment: i don't know exactly sometime it takes around 10 or 15 min

Comment: Please click on edit above at left and add that to your post, and reading https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask will help you understand what kind of information we need.